# How to uninstall standard plugins from Eclipse Mars (4.5.1)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, equinox, eclipse-mars

I want to remove most of the standard Eclipse (Mars 4.5.1) plugins (e.g. Mylyn or Git) to get a leightweight Eclipse installation.

But the *Uninstall* button in the *Installation Details* dialog is disabled for these standard plug-ins.

Is there any method to achieve this?

I tried to manually delete the jar files and update the `configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator\bundles.info` file but it is diffcult to resolve dependencies this way and does not completely remove the plug-ins.

Comment: It may be easier to start with one of the downloads from the http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.5.1-201509040015/ which has the most minimal versions of Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Eclipse packages offered on the [main Eclipse downlaods page](https://eclipse.org/downloads/) are not made for removing individual features.

As Greg commented, it is easier to start with one of the platform downloads from this page: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.5.1-201509040015/

The *Eclipse SDK*  contains apart from the core platform bundles also [JDT](https://www.eclipse.org/jdt/) and [PDE](https://www.eclipse.org/pde/). If you don't need PDE, you can also start with the *JDT SDK* download.

Once you have downloaded and started an initial minimal Eclipse, you can add desired features using *Help > Install New Software*.

Comment: Thanks for the information, _Platform Runtime Binary_ was what i wanted.